# Unable to implement jspdf using javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django, jspdf

I am trying to use jspdf to download a pdf and save it using javascript. Now, the problem is that when I try to execute jspdf function, I get this annoying error. I am using django with python. My goal is to be able to download the page using jspdf and then automatically trigger the print preview event for the user. What could I be doing wrong  ??

```
       jspdf.min.js:70 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
            at k (jspdf.min.js:70)
            at r (jspdf.min.js:70)
            at r (jspdf.min.js:70)
            at r (jspdf.min.js:70)
            at r (jspdf.min.js:70)
            at jspdf.min.js:70
            at i (jspdf.min.js:70)
            at v (jspdf.min.js:70)
            at x (jspdf.min.js:70)
            at Object.e.fromHTML (jspdf.min.js:70)
    This is what I tried so far. What could I be doing wrong?

    <div id="content">
     <div class="mdl-grid">
    <div>
    {% if messages %}
        <div >
        <ul class="messages">
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        </div>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-grid">
    <!--  profile card -->
        <!-- Square card -->
        <style>
        .demo-card-square.mdl-card {
          {#width: 320px;#}
          min-height: 200px;
          max-height: 600px;
        }
        .demo-card-square > .mdl-card__title {
          color: #fff;
            min-height: 250px;
          max-height: 250px;
          background:
            url('/media/profile.png') bottom right 15% no-repeat #3C5D73;
        }
            {#.mdl-card__supporting-text {#}
            {#     height: 320px;#}
            {#}#}
        </style>


        <div class="demo-card-square mdl-card  mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-shadow--3dp">
              <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">{{ member.get_full_name }}</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                  <input type="hidden" value={% if member.isUserActive%}Active {% else %}Inactive{% endif %} id="status"/>
                Member status - {% if member.isUserActive %}Active {% else %}Inactive{% endif %}<br>
                {{ member.get_aniversary_start }} - {{ member.get_aniversary_end }}
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__actions center-items mdl-card--border" >
                    <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-cell--3-col">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3"
                                style="background-color: #3C5D73;color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center">
                                    Cover
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="background-color: #3C5D73; color: #FFFFFF; text-align:left">
                                <td>
                                    Benefit
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Limit
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Balance
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% for benefit in member.get_benefits %}
                                <tr>
                                <td style="padding-left: 0px">
                                    {{ benefit.name }}
                                </td>
                                    <td style="padding-left: 0px">
                                        {{ benefit.limit|intcomma }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-left: 0px">
                                        {{ benefit.balance|intcomma }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                             {% endfor %}


                    </table>
              </div>

        </div>
        <!-- end profile card -->

<div class="mdl-shadow--3dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col mdl-typography--text-right">
    <form method="post" id ="preauth" action="{% url 'payments_pre_authorization_new' member.member_no %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login"/>

        <div class="mdl-grid ">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ member.get_full_name }}">
        <input type="text" id="member_no" name="member_no" value="{{ member.member_no }}">


                </select>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="mdl-grid ">
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label getmdl-select mdl-cell mdl-cell---col">
{#                <input type="text" value="" class="mdl-textfield__input"#}
{#                       id="provider" readonly>#}
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                       for="textfield_ward">Provider</label>
                        {{ form.provider }}
{#                <input type="hidden" value="" name="provider">#}
{#                <label for="provider" class="mdl-textfield__label">provider</label>#}
{#                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.provider.errors }}</span>#}
{#                <ul for="provider"#}
{#                    class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu">#}
{#                    <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="1">21st Century Insurance</li>#}
{#                    <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="2">AARP</li>#}
{#                    <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="3">ACE Limited</li>#}
{#                    <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="4">Elephant.com</li>#}
{##}
{#                </ul>#}
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--5-col">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                       for="textfield_ward">Ward</label>
{#                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.ward.errors }}</span>#}
                    {{ form.ward }}
{#                <input type="number" class="mdl-textfield__input"#}
{#                       id="id_{{ form.ward.name }}"#}
{#                       name="{{ form.ward.name }}" value="{% if form.ward.value != None %}{{ form.ward.value }}{% endif %}"#}
{#                       required>#}
            </div>
{##}
{#            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">#}
{#                <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"#}
{#                       for="textfield_anniv">Anniv</label>#}
{#                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.anniv.errors }}</span>#}
{#                <input type="number" class="mdl-textfield__input"#}
{#                       id="id_{{ form.anniv.name }}"#}
{#                       name="{{ form.anniv.name }}"#}
{#                       value="{% if form.anniv.value != None %}{{ form.anniv.value }}{% endif %}"#}
{#                       required>#}
{#            </div>#}

        </div>

        <div class="mdl-grid ">
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                       for="textfield_pre_diagnosis">Diagnosis</label>
                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.pre_diagnosis.errors }}</span>
                <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" id="id_{{ form.pre_diagnosis.name }}"
                          name="{{ form.pre_diagnosis.name }}"
                          rows="3"
                          required>{% if form.pre_diagnosis.value != None %}
                    {{ form.pre_diagnosis.value }}{% else %} {% endif %}</textarea>
            </div>


        </div>

            <div class="mdl-grid">
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col admitted">
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                           for="textfield_available_limit">Days to Admit</label>
                    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.admit_days.errors }}</span>
                    <input type="number" class="mdl-textfield__input"
                           id="id_{{ form.admit_days.name }}"
                           name="{{ form.admit_days.name }}"
                           value="{% if form.admit_days.value != None %}{{ form.admit_days.value }}{% endif %}"
                           >


                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col admitted">
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                           for="textfield_date_admitted">Date Admitted </label>
                    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.date_admitted.errors }}</span>
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="date" id="id_{{ form.date_admitted.name }}"
                           name="{{ form.date_admitted.name }}"
                           value="{% if form.date_admitted.value != None %}{{ form.date_admitted.value }} {% else %} {% endif %}"
                           >
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="mdl-grid">

            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col">
                                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                                           for="textfield_available_limit">Authority Limit</label>
                                    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.available_limit.errors }}</span>
                                    <input type="number" class="mdl-textfield__input"
                                           id="id_{{ form.available_limit.name }}"
                                           name="{{ form.available_limit.name }}"
                                           value="{% if form.available_limit.value != None %}{{ form.available_limit.value }}{% endif %}"
                                           required>


                                </div>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col admitted">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                       for="textfield_day_bed_charge">Daily Bed Limit</label>
                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.day_bed_charge.errors }}</span>
                <input type="number" class="mdl-textfield__input"
                       id="id_{{ form.day_bed_charge.name }}"
                       name="{{ form.day_bed_charge.name }}" value="{% if form.day_bed_charge.value != None %}{{ form.day_bed_charge.value }}{% endif %}"
                       >
            </div>

            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                       for="textfield_reserve">Reserve Amount</label>
                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.reserve.errors }}</span>
                <input type="number" class="mdl-textfield__input"
                       id="id_{{ form.reserve.name }}"
                       name="{{ form.reserve.name }}"
                       value="{% if form.reserve.value != None %}{{ form.reserve.value }}{% endif %}"
                       required>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="mdl-grid ">


            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                       for="textfield_date_reported">Date Reported</label>
                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.date_reported.errors}}</span>
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="date"
                       id="id_{{ form.date_reported.name }}"
                       name="{{ form.date_reported.name }}"
                       value="{% if form.date_reported.value != None %}{{ form.date_reported.value }} {% else %} {% endif %}"
                       required>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                       for="textfield_reported_by">Reported By</label>
                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.reported_by.errors }}</span>
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text"
                       id="id_{{ form.reported_by.name }}"
                       name="{{ form.reported_by.name }}"
                       value="{% if form.reported_by.value != None %}{{ form.reported_by.value }} {% else %} {% endif %}"
                       required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mdl-grid ">
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                       for="textfield_notes">Notes</label>
                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.notes.errors }}</span>
                <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" id="id_{{ form.notes.name }}"
                          name="{{ form.notes.name }}"
                          rows="3" cols="100"
                          required>{% if form.notes.value != None %}
                    {{ form.notes.value }}{% else %} {% endif %}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mdl-grid ">
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                       for="textfield_notes">Extension/Notes</label>
                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.internal_notes.errors }}</span>
                {{ form.internal_notes }}

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mdl-grid ">
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                       for="textfield_dob">Date Authorised </label>
                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.dob.errors }}</span>
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="date" id="id_{{ form.dob.name }}"
                       name="{{ form.dob.name }}"
                       value="{% if form.dob.value != None %}{{ form.dob.value }} {% else %} {% endif %}"
                       required>
            </div>


            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--9-col">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-text--grey"
                       for="textfield_authorised_by">Authorised By</label>
                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ form.authorized_by.errors }}</span>
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="id_{{ form.authorized_by.name }}"
                       name="{{ form.authorized_by.name }}"
                       value="{% if form.authorized_by.value != None %}{{ form.authorized_by.value }}{% else %}{% endif %}"
                       required>
            </div>


        </div>
{#                            {{ form|crispy }}#}


        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col send-button" align="center">

            <button id="submit" type="submit"
                    class="mdl-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-color--primary disabled">
                Submit
            </button>

             <button id="btn_print" type="submit"
                    class="mdl-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-color--primary disabled">
                PrintS Button
            </button>
        </div>


    </form>
</div>
    </div>


</div>
   <div id="editor"></div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    window.onload = onfuncload;
    function onfuncload() {
    var bla = $('#status').val();
    if(bla==='Inactive'){
        console.log('hhjfjfEntered');
        $("#preauth :input").prop("disabled", true);

    }
    console.log("blahhh",bla);

    }



$('#btn_print').click(function (e) {
    console.log('gbdhdhd')
    e.preventDefault();
   var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
        // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
        source = $('#content')[0];

         margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };
        // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
        // 'inches' in this case
        pdf.fromHTML(
            source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            margins.left, // x coord
            margins.top, { // y coord
                'width': margins.width// max width of content on PDF
            },

            function (dispose) {
                // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF
                //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                pdf.save('Test.pdf');
            }, margins
        );




});


        $('#id_authority_type').change(function() {
            var selection = $('#id_authority_type').val();
            $('.admitted').show();
            console.log(selection);
            if(selection == '1'){
                 $('.admitted').hide();
            }
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This issue](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/516) suggests that jsPDF doesn't work with `colspan` or `rowspan`.